# refer to own class in python class method when subclassing

Tags: python, class-method

I'm wanting to keep a class attribute on a base class which keeps track of all names of all its subclasses.

```py
class SomeThing(abc.ABC):
   subclass_names = set()
   def __init_subclass__(cls):
       cls.subclass_names.add(cls.__name__)
       print(cls.subclass_names)
```

However, I'm afraid that because I'm creating an abstract class, users might overwrite the class attribute I am keeping.

```py
class SomeSub(SomeThing):
    subclass_names = set()

out: {'SomeSub'}

class SomeOtherSub(SomeThing):
    pass

out: {'SomeOtherThing'} # should be {'SomeSub', 'SomeOtherThing'}
# but SomeOtherThing is registered in SomeOtherThing's, not SomeThing's subclass_names
```

Is there a way to refer to "own class" in a class method? It seems like the cls in `__init_subclass__` ends up being whichever subclass is passed in (which makes sense).

Comment: This already exists: `SomeThing.__subclasses__()`

Comment: "refer to own class in python class method when subclassing" well, the answer to the exact question here is just `SomeThing.subclass_names`.

Comment: (Though `__subclasses__` only returns *direct* subclasses, not all subclasses of subclasses, recursively.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage of [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables):

```
class SomeThing(abc.ABC):
   __subclass_names = set()
   def __init_subclass__(cls):
       cls.__subclass_names.add(cls.__name__)
       print(cls.__subclass_names)
```

As the docs say:

> Since there is a valid use-case for class-private members (namely to avoid name clashes of names with names defined by subclasses), there is limited support for such a mechanism, called name mangling. Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

This means that subclasses of `SomeThing` won't accidentally override `__subclass_names`, since they will actually have to override `_SomeThing__subclass_names` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a double-underscore to designate an attribute as private to a particular class.  Python will "name-mangle" it behind the scenes to ensure that child classes can't accidentally override it.

```
import abc

class SomeThing(abc.ABC):
   __subclass_names = set()
   def __init_subclass__(cls):
       SomeThing.__subclass_names.add(cls.__name__)
       print(SomeThing.__subclass_names)

class SomeSub(SomeThing):
    __subclass_names = set()

# {'SomeSub'}

class SomeOtherThing(SomeThing):
    pass

# {'SomeOtherSub', 'SomeSub'}
```

Comment: "to ensure that child classes can't override it." -> "to prevent *accidentally* overriding it" because you can always do use `._SomeThing__subclass_names`

Comment: I think the key here is just to use SomeThing.__subclass_names, rather than the name mangling itself. I tried this and it works with or without the __